# drawing translated paths in wrong coordinates

Tags: svg, canvas

I am trying to build a simple game for educational purposes and i am having problem with drawing object in correct coordinates.

I had svg spaceship that i wanted to utilise, so i converted it to canvas paths system using this tool [SVG to Canvas converter](http://demo.qunee.com/svg2canvas/).

Since svg was originally designed on 1000x1000 plane i had to apply scale to reach desired size

```
// calculate scale, if size (r) has to be 40px then 40px / original size (1000) = 0.04;
var size = r / 1000;
ctx.scale(size, size); // apply desired size
```

It seemed to work but then when it comes to rendering it in set coordinates (x,y), it clearly is off the mark.

In the demo you can see that ship is rotating and moving outside of where it should be, also disproportion seems to vary depending on location which clearly means something is wrong.

Maybe someone could find the cause and how i can fix it? The aim ofc is for the ship to be rendered in the center of helper box.

This is demo code:

```js
var cvs = document.querySelector('canvas'),
 ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
 w = cvs.width = 1000,
 h = cvs.height = 1000,
 helper = document.querySelector('.helper');

var ship = function(x, y, r, a) {
 var size = r / 1000; // calculate scale, if size (r) has to be 40px then 40px / original size (1000) = 0.04;
 x -= r / 2; // go back half of its width to center ship on passed x coord
 y -= r / 2; // go back half of its height to center ship on passed y coord
 
 /* draw original ship ----> */
 
 ctx.save();
 
 ctx.translate(x, y);
 ctx.scale(size, size); // apply desired size
 ctx.rotate((a + 90) * Math.PI / 180); // rotate ship on its center
 ctx.translate(-x, -y);
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(341.4,856.1);
 ctx.lineTo(173.2,881.8000000000001);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(159.79999999999998,883.8000000000001,146.5,877.7,139.39999999999998,866.2);
 ctx.lineTo(76.69999999999997,764.2);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(73.19999999999997,758.5,71.59999999999998,752,71.79999999999997,745.6);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(71.79999999999997,745.1,71.69999999999997,744.5,71.69999999999997,744);
 ctx.lineTo(71.69999999999997,528.2);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(71.69999999999997,509.6,86.79999999999997,494.50000000000006,105.39999999999998,494.50000000000006);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(123.99999999999997,494.50000000000006,139.09999999999997,509.6000000000001,139.09999999999997,528.2);
 ctx.lineTo(139.09999999999997,617.7);
 ctx.lineTo(273.79999999999995,377.80000000000007);
 ctx.lineTo(341.49999999999994,493.30000000000007);
 ctx.lineTo(341.49999999999994,856.1);
 ctx.closePath();
 
 ctx.moveTo(894.7,494.5);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(876.1,494.5,861,509.6,861,528.2);
 ctx.lineTo(861,617.7);
 ctx.lineTo(726.3,377.8);
 ctx.lineTo(658.5999999999999,493.3);
 ctx.lineTo(658.5999999999999,856.1);
 ctx.lineTo(826.8,881.8000000000001);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(840.1999999999999,883.8000000000001,853.5,877.7,860.5999999999999,866.1);
 ctx.lineTo(923.3,764.1);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(926.8,758.4,928.4,751.9,928.1999999999999,745.5);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(928.1999999999999,745,928.3,744.4,928.3,743.9);
 ctx.lineTo(928.3,528.2);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(928.3,509.6,913.3,494.5,894.7,494.5);
 ctx.closePath();
 
 ctx.moveTo(591.2,857.6);
 ctx.lineTo(533.7,900.5);
 ctx.lineTo(533.7,956.4);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(533.7,975,518.6,990.1,500.00000000000006,990.1);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(481.40000000000003,990.1,466.30000000000007,975,466.30000000000007,956.4);
 ctx.lineTo(466.30000000000007,900.5);
 ctx.lineTo(408.80000000000007,857.6);
 ctx.lineTo(408.80000000000007,484.2);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(408.80000000000007,478.2,407.20000000000005,472.3,404.20000000000005,467.2);
 ctx.lineTo(312.00000000000006,309.79999999999995);
 ctx.lineTo(470.6,27.2);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(476.6,16.6,487.8,10,500,10);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(512.2,10,523.4,16.6,529.4,27.2);
 ctx.lineTo(688.0999999999999,309.8);
 ctx.lineTo(595.8999999999999,467.20000000000005);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(592.8999999999999,472.40000000000003,591.2999999999998,478.20000000000005,591.2999999999998,484.20000000000005);
 ctx.lineTo(591.2999999999998,857.6);
 ctx.closePath();
 
 ctx.moveTo(591,318.2);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(605.3,306.4,607.4,285.09999999999997,595.5,270.8);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(591.6,266.1,555.8,224.60000000000002,500.8,224.60000000000002);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(446.3,224.60000000000002,409.1,265.40000000000003,405,270.1);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(392.7,284.1,394.1,305.5,408.1,317.70000000000005);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(414.5,323.30000000000007,422.40000000000003,326.1,430.3,326.1);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(439.6,326.1,448.90000000000003,322.20000000000005,455.5,314.70000000000005);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(461.2,308.40000000000003,480.4,292.1,500.8,292.1);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(524.7,292.1,543.6,313.8,543.6,313.8);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(555.5,328,576.7,330.1,591,318.2);
 ctx.closePath();
 
 ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
 
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.restore();
 
 /* <---- draw original ship */
};

var c = { x: 100, y: 100, a: 270, r: 40 };

var rotator = 1;

var render = function() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
 ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

 ship(c.x, c.y, c.r, c.a);
 
 c.x += rotator;
 c.y += rotator;
 c.a += rotator;
 
 if(c.x >= 950 || c.y >= 950 || c.x <= 50 || c.y <= 50) {
  rotator *= -1;
 }
 
 /* helper debug section ----> */
 ctx.save();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(c.x, 0);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x, 1000);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0, c.y);
 ctx.lineTo(1000, c.y);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(c.x, c.y);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x, c.y - 20);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x - 20, c.y - 20);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x - 20, c.y);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x - 20, c.y + 20);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x, c.y + 20);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x + 20, c.y + 20);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x + 20, c.y);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x + 20, c.y - 20);
 ctx.lineTo(c.x, c.y - 20);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.restore();
 /* <---- helper debug section */

 requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

render();
```

```css
canvas {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice thing to know is that you can draw svg paths in canvas using [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) as I did in the next demo. Also I've recalculated your path. The path you are using is 1000/1000 units. I've recalculated your path to begin at -500 both in x and y, putting the center in the origin: point {x:0,y:0}.

```js
let svgPath =`M-158.60000000000002,356.1L-326.8,381.79999999999995C-340.2,383.79999999999995,-353.5,377.70000000000005,-360.6,366.20000000000005L-423.3,264.20000000000005C-426.8,258.5,-428.4,252,-428.2,245.60000000000002,-428.2,245.10000000000002,-428.3,244.5,-428.3,244L-428.3,28.200000000000045C-428.3,9.600000000000023,-413.2,-5.5,-394.6,-5.5,-376,-5.5,-360.9,9.600000000000023,-360.99,28.200000000000045L-360.9,117.70000000000005,-226.2,-122.19999999999999,-158.5,-6.699999999999989,-158.5,356.1
M394.70000000000005,-5.5C376.1,-5.5,361,9.600000000000023,361,28.200000000000045L361,117.70000000000005,226.29999999999995,-122.19999999999999,158.69000000000005,-6.699999999999989,158.60000000000002,356.1,326.79999999999995,381.79999999999995C340.20000000000005,383.79999999999995,353.5,377.70000000000005,360.6,366.1L423.29999999999995,264.1C426.79999999999995,258.4,428.4,251.89999999999998,428.20000000000005,245.5,428.20000000000005,245,428.29999999999995,244.39999999999998,428.29999999999995,243.89999999999998,428.29999999999995,9.600000000000023,413.29999999999995,-5.5,394.70000000000005,-5.5z
M91.20000000000005,357.6L33.700000000000045,400.5,33.700000000000045,456.4C33.700000000000045,475,18.600000000000023,490.1,0,490.1,-18.600000000000023,490.1,-33.69999999999999,475,-33.69999999999999,456.4L-33.69999999999999,400.5,-91.19999999999999,357.6,-91.13,-15.800000000000011C-91.19999999999999,-21.80000000000001,-92.80000000000001,-27.69999999999999,-95.80000000000001,-32.80000000000001L-188,-190.2,-29.399999999999977,-472.8C-23.399999999999977,-483.4,-12.199999999999989,-490,0,-490,12.200000000000045,-490,23.399999999999977,-483.4,29.399999999999977,-472.8L188.10000000000002,-190.2,95.89999999999998,-32.80000000000001C92.89999999999998,-27.569999999999993,91.29999999999995,-21.80000000000001,91.29999999999995,-15.800000000000011L91.29999999999995,357.6z
M91,-181.8C105.29999999999995,-193.60000000000002,107.39999999999998,-214.89999999999998,95.5,-229.2,91.60000000000002,-233.89999999999998,55.799999999999955,-275.4,0.8000000000000114,-275.4,-53.69999999999999,-275.4,-90.89999999999998,-234.60000000000002,-95,-229.89999999999998,-107.30000000000001,-215.89999999999998,-105.89999999999998,-194.5,-91.89999999999998,-182.3,-85.5,-176.7,-77.60000000000002,-173.89999999999998,-69.69999999999999,-173.89999999999998,-60.39999999999998,-173.89999999999998,-51.10000000000002,-177.8,-44.5,-185.3,-38.80000000000001,-191.60000000000002,-19.600000000000023,-207.89999999999998,0.8000000000000114,-207.89999999999998,24.700000000000045,-207.89999999999998,43.60000000000002,-186.2,43.60000000000002,-186.2,55.5,-172,76.70000000000005,-169.89999999999998,91,-181.8z`;


var cvs = document.querySelector('canvas'),
 ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
 w = cvs.width = window.innerWidth,
 h = cvs.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
let shuttle = new Path2D(svgPath);


let angle = 0;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let increment = 1


let the_scale = .1;
//helper size
//1000 is the size of the svg path
let hs = (1000 * the_scale) / 2;


function frame(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w,h )
  angle += increment/100;
  x+=increment;
  if(y < h + hs){y+=increment;}else{y = -hs; x=-hs;}
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle="#333"
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.scale(the_scale,the_scale);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.fill(shuttle);
 
  ctx.restore();
  
  helper(x,y)
}

frame();


function helper(x,y){
  ctx.strokeStyle="red"
  ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
 ctx.lineTo(x, h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0, y);
 ctx.lineTo(w, y);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(x, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x, y - hs);
 ctx.lineTo(x - hs, y - hs);
 ctx.lineTo(x - hs, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x - hs, y + hs);
 ctx.lineTo(x, y + hs);
 ctx.lineTo(x + hs, y + hs);
 ctx.lineTo(x + hs, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x + hs, y - hs);
 ctx.lineTo(x, y - hs);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
canvas{background:#d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: very nice approach, although Path2D has shady support, but it works nicely, thank you sir ;)